# TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, types

I am creating a turn based combat system for a small game and I am receiving the error

> TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()

in the line:

```
AImove = random.choice(AImove)
```

For reference, the `AImove` variable is set out as follows:

```
AImove = [1,2]
```

I have tried to add `AImove = int` and `AImove = str` into the code but I either receive the same error as before or `"TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()"`

The function where `AImove` is used appears below, any feedback would be appreciated.

```
def combat(health, turn, loop, gold, AImove):

    enemy_health = (random.choice(random_enemy_Health))
    enemy_attack = (random.choice(random_enemy_Attack))
    print("\nYou are fighting a" ,random.choice(enemies), "with an attack amount of" ,enemy_attack, "and a health amount of" ,enemy_health,".")
    while health > 0 and enemy_health > 0:
        if turn == 1:
            while loop == False:
                print("\nDo you want to attack or flee? Type '1' to attack and '2' to flee.")
                response=input()
                if response == "1":
                        enemy_health = enemy_health - attack
                        print("You attacked!")
                        loop = True                       
                elif response == "2":
                    hub_travel()
                    print ("You fled the battle, come back once you are stronger!")
                    loop = True
                else:
                    print ("Invalid number, try again")
                    continue
            turn = 2                                                    

        if turn == 2:
                AImove = random.choice(AImove)
                if AImove == 1:
                    print ("Enemy attacked!")
                    health = health - enemy_attack
                if AImove == 2:
                    print("Enemy missed!")
                turn = 1                                                    
                continue
```

Comment: `AImove = random.choice(AImove)` Once that code executes, the name `AImove` no longer refers to the original list, but to the chosen integer.  So the second time it tries to execute, you get the error.

Comment: How would I go about keeping the same functionality but removing the error? The random selection has to remain there.

Comment: Use a different name, such as: `AIchoice = random.choice(AImove)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You immediatly replace `AImove` with the result of `random.choice`, afterwards it's either `1` or `2` and in the next iteration you try `random.choice(1)` (or `2`) which explains the exception you've seen.

You could simply use another variable name there:

```
# ...
AImove_this_turn = random.choice(AImove)
if AImove_this_turn == 1:
    print ("Enemy attacked!")
    health = health - enemy_attack
if AImove_this_turn == 2:
    print("Enemy missed!")
turn = 1                                                    
continue
```